# InAppBrowser Ionic testing browser doesn't display page says cannot GET my url

Tags: html, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to create an iOS and android App, I have a list view that displays name of a website and url from a json file.  I am displaying the  json just fine but I am getting an error in testing in the DevApp on my iPhone.  it say cannot GET/myURLString from my json. it displays the url string.

Here is what I have.  Can someone help, Im connected to wifi and the url in the address bar says after i click the listview item.  localhost:8102/www.myjsonblahblah.net

my resources.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>Resources & Information</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

```
<ion-item><p text-wrap>Our Resources page will offer adding new resources and finding a team your area.</p></ion-item>
<ion-buttons>

    <button ion-button full large color="secondary" style="color: #000000;">Add a resource!</button>
    <button ion-button full large color="secondary" style="color: #000000;">Find a team in your area!</button>
  </ion-buttons>

<ion-list>
    <button ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let item of filteredList" (click)="openWebpage(item.post.URL)">
      <h4 text-wrap>{{item.post.Name}}</h4>
      <p>{{item.post.URL}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

my resource.ts file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
    import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser";



    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-resources',
      templateUrl: 'resources.html',
    })
    export class ResourcesPage {
      url: any;
      tournments: any[];
      filteredList = [];
      listType = 'all';

      constructor(
      private navCtrl: NavController,
      private dataProvider: DataProvider, private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {
        this.dataProvider.getResource().subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.tournments = data.posts;
  this.filteredList = this.tournments;
  this.url = data.posts;
        });
      }

      openWebpage(url: string) {
        const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  zoom: 'yes',
  toolbar: 'yes',
  enableViewportScale: 'yes',
        }

        // Opening a URL and returning an InAppBrowserObject
        const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_system', options);
        console.log(url);
        console.log(browser);
        console.log("link viewed");

       // Inject scripts, css and more with browser.X
      }

      /**
       * open Resoures detail page
       * 
       * @param tournament 
       */
      openResourcePage(tournament: any) {
        this.navCtrl.push('ResourceDetailPage', {tournament: tournament});
      }

      /**
       * search by text
       */
      onSearch(event: any) {
        const searchText = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        this.filteredList = this.tournments.filter(item => {
          if ((item.post.NAME as                         string).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
    return true;
          }
  return false;
          });
        }

      segmentChanged(event: any) {
        this.dataProvider.getResource(event.value).subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.tournments = data.posts;
          this.filteredList = this.tournments;
        });
      }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using Ionic version #3? 
According to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/, you could try setting your target from '_system' to '_self'.

Comment: I’ve tried self system and blank with the same resuly